# Anyone know if there are any large chains that carry HT Armaflex?

Tags: materials

Grainger doesn't have it, Northern Tool doesn't have it, and Lowes doesn't have it.  Home Depot has a lower temperature (200F) Armaflex, but doesn't have HT Armaflex.  (HT Armaflex, by the way, is a high-temperature rubberized pipe insulation.)

Does anyone know where I can get this stuff?  :(

PS: I'm in DFW, TX.

Comment: You may want to re-word your question and include some specifics to keep it from getting closed. (Although, it might just get closed for being off-topic or too localized anyway.) First off, what's the temperature rating you're looking for? What are you going to use it for, etc. Also, you may want to specify that Armaflex is pipe insulation - at least that's what I got from Google. Would another brand work? If not, why? The more information you give us, the more we can help.

Comment: It's for a solar hot water job.  I've read two books on solar hot water and taken a training course, and all I've ever seen recommended is HT Armaflex.  I couldn't tell you what's special about it, though, because it seems to me that if something can withstand 300F or better, it should work(?)

Comment: You can always try contacting the company, and ask if there's any distributors locally ... when telling their website US/TX, I got : http://www.armacell.com/www/armacell/INETArmacell.nsf/web/801DE9F5CA2C46D7C1257713005B6415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike, check out your local HVAC professional supply houses.  I didn't try it, but often times the manufacture's web site with have links to suppliers also.